# iPhone popen can't read stdout

Tags: iphone, popen, jailbreak

I am attempting to execute a shell command from inside an iPhone app I am writing. The app is for jail broken devices. I need to catch the stdout of the command to display it in the app. I know that popen is executing the command because xcode's gdb is showing the output.  Also the file pointer returned is not null however when I try to read the first character of the stream it immediately reaches the eof. Can anyone tell me how I can read the stdout?

Comment: I have the same problem, any luck?

Comment: I ended up using nstask instead and I was able to get output from that. to use it I had to copy the nstask header file in to my project folder

Comment: Wow, that is a great idea! I thought that NSTask totally didn't exist, but thanks, I will be using that instead of system redirected output to a file :D